# Limit of a function in infinity and in zero plus

Tags: limits

Calculate the following limits:

$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x}+x^2}{x+\sqrt{x}}$

$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x}+x^2}{x+\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. People downvoted your question because you didn't show what you were able to do so far and where you got stuck. You got answers anyway, but that may not happen next time. And please ask only one question at a time.

Comment: Ok, I understand, thank you

Comment: Good. Next step: if you learn from the answers, upvote them (the up arrow), You may upvote many, but can accept just one (the checkmark),

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

As gcd$(2,3)=6,$ choose $\sqrt[6]x=\dfrac1y, \sqrt[2]x=\dfrac1{y^3}$ etc. for the first case and $y\to0^+$ as $x\to+\infty$

and $\sqrt[6]x=u,\sqrt[3]x=u^2$ for the second

Answer (score 0):

writ your first term in the form $$\frac{x^2(\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{x}+1)}{x(1+\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x})}$$
for the second Substitute $x=t^6$ and we have $$\frac{t^2+t^{12}}{t^6+t^3}$$

Comment: Thanks, $\lim_{x \to \infty} x\ \frac{\frac{1}{x^{5/3}}+1}{1+\frac{1}{x^{1/2}}} = +\infty$

Comment: For the second one I have $\frac{1+t^{10}}{t(t^3+1)}$ and I don't know what's next. I have $[\frac{1}{0}]$

Comment: for $x$ tends to zero $t$ tends to zero, thus no limit exists.

Comment: We can see from the plot that the limit is $+ \infty$ https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(x)+%3D+(x%5E(1%2F3)%2Bx%5E2)%2F(x%2Bsqrt(x))+on+R

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple with *equivalents*:

1. $\sqrt[3]{x}+x^2 \sim_\infty x^2$, $\;x+\sqrt{x}\sim_\infty x$, so
   $\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}+x^2}{x+\sqrt{x}}\sim_\infty\frac{x^2}x=x.$
2. $\sqrt[3]{x}+x^2 \sim_0\sqrt[3]{x} $, $\;x+\sqrt{x}\sim_{0^+} \sqrt x$, so
   $\;\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}+x^2}{x+\sqrt{x}}\sim_{0^+}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{\sqrt x}=\frac{x^{2/6}}{x^{3/6}}=\frac1{x^{1/6}}.$